# How do you disable all of the controls inside panel's but enable some specified controls?

Tags: asp.net

I have asp:panel with some controls, the mark-up as below

```
<asp:panel id="panel1" runat="server">
    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="aaaa"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="bbbb"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="cccc"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt1"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt2"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtn1" runat="server"/>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtn2" runat="server"/>
</asp:panel>
```

Now I want to disable all the controls, but enabling ibtn1 and ibtn2

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    panel1.Enabled = False
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_PreRender(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
    ibtn1.Enabled = True
    ibtn2.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

All of the controls are disabled, that's great, but not for ibtn1 and ibtn 2.

Then, I have tried this method instead

```
Public Sub lDisableAllChildControls(ByRef p As WebControl)
    For Each c As System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl In p.Controls
        c.Enabled = False
        'recurse
        lDisableAllChildControls(c)
    Next
End Sub
```

but it gave me this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl'

Does anyone has any idea to make this work? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you replace with Control, because your label is litteral

```
 For Each c As System.Web.UI.Control.Control In p.Controls

 Next
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, do you mean System.Web.UI.Control? If so, it said "Enable is not a member of System.Web.UI.Control"

Comment: I'am happy to help you user14399709, you can add cast of your control with type checck, if c is WebControl ....

Comment: Thanks for your tips Candie
I have tried to modified the code to 
<code>Public Sub lDisableAllChildControls(p As WebControl)
        For Each c As Control In p.Controls
            Dim wc As WebControl = TryCast(c, WebControl)
            If wc IsNot Nothing Then
                wc.Enabled = False
                'recurse
                lDisableAllChildControls(c)
            End If

        Next
 End Sub</code>
Everything works fine. But the user controls inside the panel that can not be disabled.